# Como colocar uma imageView e um textView dentro de um gridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

Não consigo colocar imagem e texto dentro de um gridView, alguém pode me ajudar ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisará trabalhar com ArrayAdapters.
Aqui tem um tutorial com exatamente o que voce precisa: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html